# Dividing matrix values by the size of the matrix produces error

Tags: matlab, matrix, division

I have a matrix 1080x1920 double. I want to divide the matrix by it's size. However, it returns an error.

```
[n m] = size(a);
a/[n m];
**Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.**
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some example of a matrix and the result you want to get? I don't really understand what dividing a matrix by its size means

Answer (score 1):

When you use `[n m]=size(a)`, n is the number of line and m is the number of column (or row) : then [n m] is a line-matrix with 2 elements.

If I'm right, you're trying to divide a by the number of element in a. So wheter you do `a/(n*m)` or you can use too the function `length` since `n*m=length(a)` (the `length` function gives you the number of element in the input matrix.

Otherwise, if you're trying to do the matrix multiplication `a/[n m]` or `a*([n m]^-1)`, the dimension of the matrices `a` and `[n m]` have to be mathematically consistent to perform such a matrix multiplication.